# Send Email After User has confirmed email address using Rules

Tags: 7, rules, emails

I my drupal site, I have checked **Require Email Confirmation** to enable email confirmation. In this case it is sending an email with link to confirm email to set password for account.

Now when user has confirmed email address and set password for account, I want to send email to the user informing of confirmed email.

I have looked Rules Module for this, but there is no any such even present.

Any suggestion how can I implement this using Rules module.

-- Many thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this on a site not long ago, and at the time I couldn't find a solution that would work without some extra code because of the way registration was set up, but for your case you should be able to use a rule to check when the user's access timestamp is first set, reacting to the "after updating an existing user account" event.

So you need to check the account-unchanged:last-access is 0 and the account:last-access is not 0, then fire your rule. I haven't tested that this will work, and you might need to add some extra conditions for your particular circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this condition, but it always return false. And if I use only: account-unchanged:last-access = 0, it always return true. Why this behavior?

Comment: It's possible that the access timestamp only gets set on a normal login, not using the one-time link. If so, that's arguably a core bug. Not sure of any immediate solution, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve this issue, but I think [Password Token, for sending the User the password in E-Mail](http://drupal.org/node/1165126) might be helpful in your case.

Comment: The link you mentioned in the answer points to the issue of LoginToBoggan module, and does not serve the use case mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to to create your custom rule or the other way is to use logic of workflow module.

In custom rule, once a mail has been sent and when user will confirm the email  and set a password at that time, set one flag.If flag is set then send mail and then unset that flag. In this way you can acheive.

The another way is to create states in workflow. And make workflow rules configure accordingly.

HOpe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan rules integration